# Newline in constant

Tags: c#, string

When the following code is run:

```
Response.Write("window.open('BugSummaryForPrint.aspx?prjId=" + prjId + "&prjName=" + prjName','_blank')");
```

I get this error:

```
Newline in constant
```

Help!

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Are you missing a " before prjName in the second line?

Comment: Looks like classical ASP code to me, but tell me: what scripting language you're using? VBScript or JavaScript?

Comment: Couldn't resist, tidied it up a bit. Does say C#

Answer (score 5):

As horrid of a "question" as this is, I feel helpful tonight. You were missing a couple characters (`+ "`) in your code, after you appended `prjName`.

```
Response.Write("window.open('BugSummaryForPrint.aspx?prjId=" + prjId + "&prjName=" + prjName + "','_blank')");
```

Answer (score 5):

If genuinely C# (and the fact that its a redirect to a .aspx suggests that it probably is) then you can make your life a bit easier as follows:

```
string resp = String.Format(
    "window.open('BugSummaryForPrint.aspx?prjId={0}&prjName={1}','_blank')", 
    prjId, 
    prjName
    );
Response.Write(resp);
```

You could as easily do it all in one line (do the String.Format inline with the Response.Write) I've just split it a bit for clarity.

String.Format (and other places where you can use format strings like .AppendFormat in stringbuilders) is an oft overlooked tool.